# how can i reduce the ipa file size for ios?

Tags: ios, build, sdk, frameworks, size

Hi I want to make my build size to be reduced. When I make a build the size increases to more than 700MB due to some heavy sdks. Can any one guide me how to reduce the sdk size to less the 100 MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `SDKs` directly in the app rather you should use it via creating Reference and add them from Build Phases as Library..

You should do it the way Google SDK is added to the iOS app see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project), the SDK is around 150 MB but adding the way defined in the link doesn't increase the IPA size..

Hope it helps..

Edit:

I think your problem is related to this [TTS: Ivona SDK for iOS - impelentation in Project increases the app to 200MB+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451478/tts-ivona-sdk-for-ios-impelentation-in-project-increases-the-app-to-200mb)

Comment: mainly sdk is not the issue im using TTS sdk in which i have sdk which is not more then 150 mb but the resourse is more then 6 GB but now i inlcuded less resources to test it. the problem is when i add all the resourses.